# Identification of flat surfaces in surface Triangulation

Tags: cgal, lidar

I have a point cloud (data set) (3D) representing an urban terrain consisting of flat roof surfaces (of buildings) . My aim is to figure out the flat surfaces , waterbodies from the given data set .The data set is a text file consisting of the number of points followed by their individual x , y , z co-ordinates. As a trial attempt , I have generated the 2D-Delaunay triangulation of the given data set to get the triangulated surface. Henceforth, I plan to execute a graph-traversal over the faces of the triangulation to look for neighbourhood points with nearly the same z-coordinate value and treat them as a flat surface . I am using CGAL libraries to accomplish the same in C++. Is there a better approach for identifying flat surface or my method seems decent enough ?

Comment: I think this question is formulated too broadly...do you want comments on your approach? Or are you looking for the best  algo somebody else knows about? The delaunay-triangulation part sounds nice. But still, I'm not very convinced by your approach - For instance how are you going to decide what 'nearly' is? And then: very inclined surfaces will have very different z coordinates but still are flat. You probably should rather look at the *inclination* of the triangles and compare those. Then again computational geometry is not my strength...

Answer (score 0):

You might get inspiration (or just run) [Advancing Front Reconstruction](http://doc.cgal.org/4.7/Manual/packages.html#PkgAdvancingFrontSurfaceReconstructionSummary)

No idea how your point cloud looks, but maybe [Point Set Shape Detection](http://doc.cgal.org/4.7/Manual/packages.html#PkgPointSetShapeDetection3Summary)
might help you to identify flat areas.